# Obtaining last Friday's date

Tags: r, date, xts, weekday

I can get today's date:

```
Sys.Date( )
```

But how do I get last Friday's date?

I tried:

```
library(xts)

date1 <- Sys.Date( ) 
to.weekly(date1 )
```

But this gives an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
library(lubridate)

Sys.Date() - wday(Sys.Date() + 1)
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
lastfri(Sys.Date())
```

where `lastfri` is the same as the one line function `nextfri` in the this zoo vignette, [zoo quickref vignette](http://ftp.auckland.ac.nz/software/CRAN/doc/vignettes/zoo/zoo-quickref.pdf), except that `ceiling` is replaced with `floor`.  Note that `lastfri` is vectorized, i.e. it can take a vector of input dates and produces a vector of output dates.  For example,

```
library(zoo)
Sys.Date()
## 2015-03-10
lastfri(Sys.Date() + 0:6)
## [1] "2015-03-06" "2015-03-06" "2015-03-06" "2015-03-13" "2015-03-13"
## [6] "2015-03-13" "2015-03-13"
```

Thus last Friday was March 6th and we keep getting March 6th until the day advances to to next Friday at which point the last Friday is March 13th.

Aside:  Next Friday is Friday the 13th.

Comment: I definitely was not expecting there to be a ready-made function for this. Cool.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function that finds the last date for any day of the week:

```
getlastdate <- function(day) {
library(lubridate)
dates <- seq((Sys.Date()-7), (Sys.Date()-1), by="days")
dates[wday(dates, label=T)==day]
}

getlastdate("Mon")  

# "2015-03-09"
```

Enter the day of the week in abbreviated format:  i.e.

```
Sun   Mon Tues  Wed   Thurs Fri   Sat
```

Answer (score 1):

Last Friday was 4 days ago, thus:

```
Sys.Date()-4

> Sys.Date()-4
[1] "2015-03-06"
```

OR for any day of the week, using `base`:

```
Sys.Date()-(as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$wday+2)
```

Comment: I expect the OP would like this to work for more than just Tuesdays.

Comment: While that may be true, it wasn't specified. I've added a solution using `base`.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(clock)

dt <- as_naive_time(Sys.Date())
as.Date(time_point_shift(dt, weekday(6), which = "previous")) # sunday = 1

# OR use clock_weekdays

friday <- weekday(clock_weekdays$friday)
as.Date(time_point_shift(dt, friday, which = "previous"))
```